# Questions about function COUNT('') and its variety

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Is there any difference between `COUNT('')` and `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(ColumnName)`? What approach is faster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count(*) vs Count(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Count(ColumnName)` is influenced by the value of the column. The other variants do effectively the same.

`Count(*)` is slower in some databases (MySQL amongst others), because it retrieves all fields while it doesn't have to. That's whay often `'x'` or `1` is used to be safe. SQL Server and Oracle are somewhat smarter and don't retrieve field values if they don't have to.

Note that `''` equals `NULL` on Oracle (yes it does!), which may have an undesired effect there. Not a problem for SQL Server, but you can use `1` to be safe.

Comment: "which *may* have an undesired effect.". Nice one. That **is** certainly an undesired effect, because it will always return 0 :-)

Answer (score 4):

`COUNT('')`, `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)` will return the same result. `COUNT(ColumnName)` might return a different value, because `COUNT` only counts non-null values.

Performance-wise they should be equivalent, at least on SQL-Server.